# Admin Stars Next To Name - PHP

Tags: php

Okay, so in my SQL Database, I have a list of users, some being normal users, and some being Moderators, Administrators etc, with a column in my table showing their status: 0 = Normal User, 1 = Mod, 2 = Admin etc. How could I display a certain colored star next to their name on my website, depending on what status they have on my website?

For example, as user list:
Sw0rdX [Red Star] (Admin)
Lyoco [Blue Star] (Moderator)
PMDude (Normal User)

I've seen this on some websites before, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options, either a conditional statement, or a little bit of clever image naming.

**Conditional Statement (IF)**

```
if($user['status'] == 0) {
    echo '<img src="normaluser.png" />';
} else if($user['status'] == 1) {
    echo '<img src="moduser.png" />';
} else if($user['status'] == 2) {
    echo '<img src="adminuser.png" />';
}
```

**Conditional Statement (switch)**

```
switch($user['status']) {

 case 0: echo '<img src="normaluser.png" />'; break;
 case 1: echo '<img src="moduser.png" />'; break;
 case 2: echo '<img src="adminuser.png" />'; break;
}
```

**Filenaming**

```
echo '<img src="userimage_'.$user['status'].'.png" />';
```

With the filenaming option, you basically create your star images with all the same name, and just have the status number as the only difference in the names, then when you echo the status number, it will display the correct star for that status

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this and then use styles to make the star the color you want.

```
if ($status == 2){
    echo "<span class='gold'>*</span>".$name;
} elseif($status = 1) {
    echo "<span class='red'>*</span>".$name;
} else {
    echo $name;
}
```

If you want to display images:

```
if ($status == 2){
    echo "<img src="images/gold_star.gif" alt="gold star"/>".$name;
} elseif($status = 1) {
    echo "<img src="images/red_star.gif" alt="red star"/>".$name;
} else {
    echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check their status and then make some if/elseif or switch function to write what you want

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you have a clear understanding of MVC architecture and explained in the notations of ZendFramework. Which i hope will be self explanatory.

in your controller you obtain the data for the user you will be displaying, then you pass the dataset to your view.

```
function someAction() {
     $profile = $this->getProfileData(1);
     $this->view->assign('profile', $profile);
}
```

with in the view where your displaying the star, you will run the logic you needed. Ideally this should be done using a viewHelper but i am going to write an ugly function on the view now.

```
<div><?php echo $this->profile->name; ?> <?php switch ($this->profile->status) {
 case 0:
     echo '<img src="redstart.gif" />';
     break;
 case 1:
     echo '<img src="bluestar.gif" />';
     break;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
if($user_status=="admin")
{
echo "<img sre='http://cdn2.content.compendiumblog.com/uploads/user/a4e707ba-e52c-41ea-b5df-e22be41ea981/521b88f2-74f9-4a03-9122-54f4648c5ebb/Image/517afb724262d61d2d2848b5ef64a346/red_star_left.jpg' />";
}
elseif($user_status=="mod")
{
echo "<img sre'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Blue_Star.svg/240px-Blue_Star.svg.png' />";
}
else
{
echo "Normal user";
}
```

This is where $user_status, is the current users status.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly basic approach. I haven't tested this code, but hopefully you'll get the idea...

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT username, status from users where login_id = '" . $username . "';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["username"];

    switch ($row['status']) {

        case 2: 
            echo "<img src="redstar.png";
            break;
        case 1:
            echo "<img src="bluestar.png";
            break;

    }

}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: Just noticed you mentioned SQL not mySQL. Hopefully you can work it out from about anyway as the principle is the same